# Facebook ignoring open graph meta tags

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have specified og meta tags on my single blog post pages because facebook is pulling preview images from the sidebar instead of the main content area, however they don't seem to be working. When I load the url in the debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), I get these warnings:

Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Here's my source, there's no iframe being used or anything like that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3718.png

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The og-tags are not there when I look at the source of http://rachelrodgerslaw.com/sitting-on-buried-treasure-5-steps-to-capitalizing-on-your-intellectual-property/

Comment: Sorry the rest of the url was cut off and I thought you were talking about the home page. Thanks for pointing out that you didn't see it, the cache hadn't updated even though I added the tags about a week ago... all is good now.

Answer (score 0):

I initially had this problem, but I then moved my meta tags to the bottom of the  section, and the sharing debugger started paying attention to them.